# Error "<-1> but was:<2147483647>". Tell me please, what's wrong with the code?

Tags: java, string

Write a method that will withdraw money from a particular customer's account and return the balance on the account. If there is not enough money on the account, the method will return -1

The signature of the method - `withdraw (String [] clients, int [] balances, String client, int amount)`

```
    package Lesson5;

/**
 * Created by Ruslan on 12.06.2017.
 */
public class takeOffBalance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clients[] = {"John", "Pedro", "Valera", "Muchachos", "Vovan"};
        int [] balances = {1, 100, 3500, 222, 1234};
        System.out.println(withdraw(clients, balances, "Pedro", (int) 10000));
    }

    static int withdraw(String[] clients, int[] balances, String client, int amount) {

        int res = balances[findClient(clients, client)] - amount;
        return res >= 0 ? res : -1;

    }
    static int findClient (String [] clients, String client) {

        int clientIndex = 0;
        for (String name : clients) {
            if (name == client) {
                break;
            }
            clientIndex++;
        }
        return clientIndex;
    }


}
```

Comment: This code outputs -1. Where's the unit test?

Comment: boom! this here: ***if (name == client)***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ The code as provided wouldn't be affected by that. Reopening until we have more info.

Comment: @shmosel It is an excersise whats the point with a unit test withoout running regressions...

Comment: @patrik The error message in the title looks like it's from a unit test. It's definitely not produced by the posted code.

Comment: @shmose so you mean the result of the the index variable will not be affected by this:  ***if (name == client)*** ????

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Not in this example because `"Pedro" == "Pedro"`. And if it was affecting the index variable, it would cause a AIOOBE.

Comment: What about `-1 - (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L)`?

Comment: @chuckskull What about it? There are many ways to arrive at 2147483647. Btw, `(int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @shmosel This might be the issue!.

Comment: So far I see no issue.

Comment: OP should check for negative amounts and negative balance and return -1.

Comment: Why would the balance ever be negative?

Comment: It is a negative test. As the title suggests, it is being tested by some kind of testing framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. You should check for negative amount and balances. It looks like there is a negative test that is failing.

```
static int withdraw(String[] clients, int[] balances, String client, int amount) {

    int index = findClient(clients, client);
    if (index == -1) // no client found
        return -1;
    // Negative balance, negative amount and insufficient credit.
    if(balances[index] < 0 || amount < 0 || balances[index] - amount < 0)
        return  -1;

    return balances[index] - amount;

}

static int findClient (String [] clients, String client) {

    int clientIndex = 0;
    for (String name : clients) {
        if (null != name && name.equals(client)) {
            break;
        }
        clientIndex++;
    }
    return -1; //no client found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for negative amounts, also there is no check for the case if account doesn't exist. You need to add all these validations to make it work properly.